# Select corresponding rows from another table for each row in first table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **users**, another table called **withdraws**,

How do I select a row for each withdraw request from the user with his bank details which are in the users table.

IMPORTANT : **user_name in users table is unique for each row. this is corresponding to the userid in withdraws table**

Here is, 
**Users Table**

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
| user_name | bank_ac         | ifsc        |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
| H6426012  | 456456 | ifsc6544 |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Withdraws Table**

```
+----------+--------+--------+
| userid   | amount | status |
+----------+--------+--------+
| H6426012 | 300.00 |      1 |
| H6426012 | 150.00 |      1 |
| H6426012 | 200.00 |      1 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

Here is the query I am using :

```
select withdraws.userid 
     , withdraws.amount
     , users.user_name
     , users.ifsc
     , users.bank_ac 
  from withdraws 
  JOIN users 
    on withdraws.userid = users.user_name 
 where withdraws.status = 1
```

This is the result I am expecting :

**I am expecting this result**

```
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
| userid   | amount | status |user_name   | ifsc | bank_ac |
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
| H6426012 | 300.00 |      1 | H6426012 | ifsc6544 | 456456 |
| H6426012 | 150.00 |      1 | H6426012 | ifsc6544 | 456456|
| H6426012 | 200.00 |      1 | H6426012 | ifsc6544 | 456456 |
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
```

**BUT I am getting this result**

```
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
| userid   | amount | status |user_name   | ifsc | bank_ac |
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
| H6426012 | 300.00 |      1 | NULL      | NULL    | NULL |
| H6426012 | 150.00 |      1 | NULL      | NULL    | NULL|
| H6426012 | 200.00 |      1 | NULL      | NULL    | NULL |
+----------+--------+--------++----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Quite impossible with the query you're using. If you would use a `LEFT JOIN`, then I'd say "check for invisible characters" or something. But with your current query you would either get your desired result or no result at all.

Comment: I have used LEFT JOIN also, but still getting same result.

Comment: the NULL values are not possible with your current query RameshPareek  @fancyPants is right see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWEFa4Ka6xLG7cg8HoaJ3q/0

Comment: sorry for the red flag guys. The reason was that database was updated with NULL values. so your comments really helped me to have another look into the database actually what values were actually there, and found that it was NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I ran the same query and it worked just fine, I also created the same query but without any joins, and it worked as well...
I am using SQL Server Management Studio V17.9.

Comment: Accpeting your answer :). Thanks for the effort. I already realized that the values were actually NULL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First change **user_name** to **user_id** on your **users** schema/table so as it will not confuse you in future. and then, modify your query like below then it will work fine

```
select users.userid as user_id, 
     withdraws.amount as amount,
     withdraws.status as status
     users.ifsc as ifsc
     users.bank_ac as bank_ac
  from withdraws 
  JOIN users 
    on withdraws.userid = users.userid 
 where withdraws.status = 1
```